# scala set, ambiguous reference to overloaded definition

Tags: scala, set

why do i have this error?

> Error:(5, 18) ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both
>   method startsWith in class String of type (x$1: String)Boolean and 
>   method startsWith in class String of type (x$1: String, x$2:
>   Int)Boolean match expected type ? fruit filter (_.startsWith == "ap")

val fruit = Set("app", "b", "c")

fruit filter (_.startsWith == "ap")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to use incorrect syntax. startsWith method of String accepts string as argument and returns boolean. So the correct usage is:

```
fruit filter (_.startsWith("ap"))
```